# The implication of (a 5%) significance level with a t-distribution in order to conclude a real difference

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

There is this standard in much of social "sciences" to use a 5% significance level to determine a significant degree of difference between two samples. That is two standard deviations. It seems A LOT to me (who once played some Yahtzee). So I might have misunderstood the interpretation.

Let's say that a small web shop has tried out two different web page designs. Both have generated the same sample size and standard deviation with respect to the same revenue variable, only their means differ.

Does the difference between their **means** REALLY has to be an entire two standard deviations apart (in the t-distribution) for there to be a significant difference between the two at the 5% significance level? Is there really still even a 5% chance that the 2 stdev worse one will come out ahead, on a purely mathematical basis as if this was about dice throws?

Comment: If you have two normally distributed random variables $X$ and $Y,$ both with standard deviation $1,$ and $E(Y)=E(X)+2$ (means are $2$ s.d. apart), there is a $7.8\%$ chance that $X > Y.$ But that's not how the $t$ test is done, anyway: there's an extra scaling factor from the number of observations which means you may not need a large difference of means in order to get a large $t$-statistic.

Comment: Great comment! I think I get it. Comparing means of different potential samples representing the population is different, via the t-test, from simply saying that 5% or so of a sample are further from the mean than this.